# How Do You Delete Vertices That Aren't Seen By Camera Using Geometry Nodes?

Tags: mesh, node-editor, geometry-nodes, grease-pencil

I've been trying to recreate the Grease Pencil Line Art Modifier using Geometry Nodes. I'm pretty close, but I'm wondering: How do you delete vertices that aren't seen by the camera? I've been trying to use the raycast node, but whenever I do, nothing happens. I'm specifically trying to remove the edges in the back of the model, so I can move the geometry nodes to be seen at the front without the back edges being seen.
If I were to sum up the effect I'm trying to achieve in text:
Send out raycast
If not hit, delete vertice

[image: What's Visible:]

[image: What Needs to be Deleted:]
[image: Nodetree:]

Comment: Hello and welcome! Does this answer your question? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/268525/deleting-faces-that-are-not-visible-from-certain-direction/