# Remove invisible (inner) faces

Tags: python, geometry-nodes, select, visibility

My question is very similar to [this theme](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/268525/deleting-faces-that-are-not-visible-from-certain-direction)

[quellenform](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/145249/quellenform) shared great example for polys, visible in camera

I can't to remake nodes for polys, visible in all directions, to delete all inside geometry.

This is an example
[image]
I want only visible polys here
[image]
In this video i did that with "select brush" https://youtu.be/NlDyPYREcwQ

Help me to do this with GN.

UPD: Better Example
[image]
all mesh parts are solid non-cross sub-meshes

UPD2: Add real model + 6axis mod of @quellenform 's nodetree

[image]

[image]

UPD3: simple remove from itself raycasting
I think this is tha way, but needed raycast from world sphere, what do you think?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, have you tried using a boolean modifier ?

Comment: No, boolean is not for my task. My aim is optimisation electronic details with complex body and many diodes inside? to get only visible poly-faces.
Body has gaps, has wall-thickness and not waterclosed, boolean don't solve my task.

Comment: Shoot a ray from every corner of every polygon in the direction of its face normal. If all rays hit the back of another face, then they're inside another mesh. You do need manifold meshes or else this won't always be true. But if you're working with non-manifold meshes the very concept of "inner" faces doesn't make sense. :)

Comment: As @Gorgious said, a boolean modifier set on *Union* does what you are looking for, even with letting you decide if you want *Fast* or *Exact* solver. Why wouldn't be for your task ?

Comment: @Gorgious
I work with manifold meshes from CAD

Comment: @Lutzi
This is an example https://ibb.co/bLbtP7X

Comment: @Gorgious , can you describe your idea in nodes, please? I can't reply it
https://i.ibb.co/myFzmcP/Screenshot-20240307-202146.jpg

Comment: From the video, it seems cubes and sphere are the same mesh, right? Any rules to know who is to be cut and who is the cutter?

Comment: @lemon
this is one of my model: 
https://gitlab.com/robossembler/cnc/cubic-modular-workspace
this is complex body with many parts,
any part is solid body with thickness.
I need to get only visible polys of this complex mesh in single object

Comment: could you share it in  blend format? As I imagine it, it won't be possible to do the job with GN and without booleans...

Comment: @lemon for simple test you can creale model like on last image of my first post, i share new example. Booleans is not helps, because not all objects has crossed parts. I thought it would be better to proceed from the principle of polygon visibility like https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/268532/184606

Comment: Your second example illustrates a different problem from the first example. The second one is magnitudes more complex because depending on the viewing angle and the field of view value you can almost always find a certain number of spots in the 3D world where you can see the entirety of the mesh sphere inside the construct.

Comment: @Gorgious, lemon
Help me, guys! 
I was added real model and my wip nodetree

Comment: @brothermechanic You want to only keep visible faces from one *static* point of view, no camera movement/animation in your renders ? What kind of materials will you have, only diffuse/glossy, or also transparent/translucent/SSS ?

Comment: Looking at the model, I'm really unsure of what should be removed or not...

Comment: @Lutzi no, no render, i need 3d model with keeping visible faces only

Comment: UPD3 is nearest result for now, but some ourside faces of legs are lost, and i think i need raycasting from world sphere,

Comment: (last update 3), I don't think you can have better than that. I've tested similar thing with position + scaled to low value normal before raycast, but this is quite the same. And that removes parts that you would want to keep...

Comment: I guess one idea for testing for 'visibility from anywhere' on a non-manifold mesh  with internal features would be to use the rernderer. Set up suitable pass with no bounce, light it with a white world, bake, and use GN to cull all faces with no white image texture?

Comment: @lemon 
sadly to lost this outside faces on the legs https://ibb.co/8m5M09g

Comment: @RobinBetts thank you, this is good idea. I will try to bake white world to vertex color! But I can't believe this can't be done with a Raycast node....

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151960/discussion-on-question-by-brothermechanic-remove-invisible-inner-faces); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.